# Как установить размеры рабочей области окна?

Tags: gui, jframe, java, окно

Требуется рабочая область была размеров, чтобы была как раз для компонента с высотой и шириной w и h. Но когда я устанавливаю для Окна (JFrame) размер окна

```
setSize(w, h)
```

то тут учитывается ещё и высота заголовка, потому приходится всё время писать

```
setSize(w, h + /*где-то*/ 40)
```

Как установить размеры рабочей области окна?

Comment: кто-то что-то понял ?

Comment: посмотрите методы setPreferedSize, setMinimumSize и setMaximumSize))) я из вопроса мало что понял, но решение кроется где-то среди указанных мной методов.

Comment: для того чтоб не ставать на такие грабли надо почитать как работают layout managers. по сути каждый элемент GUI - контейнер для других элементов, и очевидно что он не может иметь размер меньше чем его содержимое (хотя это утверждение не всегда верно, мы можем исопльзовать скролбары + есть layout менеджеры которые подгоняют размер дочерних элементов относительно размеров контейнера, напр: grid layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> кто-то что-то понял ?
>
> я из вопроса мало что понял

Чего непонятно-то? ТС создает окно высотой `h`. Т.к. у окна есть заголовок высотой `/*где-то*/ 40`, то высота клиентской области получается `h - 40`. В связи с этим, ТС ищет способ подогнать размеры окна, исходя из точных требуемых размеров клиентской области.

**Собственно, решение.** Кидаем на окно `JPanel`, задаем ему `preferredSize`, просим окно сделать `pack()`.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: > Чего непонятно-то?

Зачем придиратся к человеку, это не имеет отношения ни к вопросу ни к ответу? Если вам понятно что-то, то это еще не означает что оно понятно всем. Раз вы этого непонимаете, значит и вам не все понятно...

Comment: Это не придирка, это приглашение к дискуссии. ) Разве вы этого не понимаете?

> это не имеет отношения ни к вопросу ни к ответу?

Это имеет отношение к комментариям выше. Если всем будет удобнее, могу вынести этот фрагмент из ответа в комментарии к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

```
// форма        
JFrame fr = new JFrame();

// размер        
Dimension dim;

// нужная ширина (подставить число)                                
dim.width = needed_Width;

// нужная высота (подставить число)        
dim.height = needed_Height;

// присваиваем форме нужные размеры      
fr.setPreferredSize( dim );      


// JVM "прорисовывает" форму, получая реальные размеры рабочей области

fr.pack();                        

// реальная ширина рабочей области

int realWidth = fr.getContentPane().getWidth();

// реальная высота рабочей области  
int realHeight = fr.getContentPane().getHeight(); 

// вычисляем разницу по ширине        
int theXaddition = dim.width - realWidth;

// вычисляем разницу по высоте

int theYaddition = dim.height - realHeight;

// добавляем разницу к первоначально заданным размерам        
dim.width += theXaddition;

dim.height += theYaddition;

// устанавливаем увеличенные размеры

fr.setPreferredSize( dim );

// прорисовываем повторно

fr.pack();

// максимально подробно для начинающих
```